# NEXTJS - Production Build Error - panicked at 'the global thread pool has not been initialized

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, node-modules

I am using Heroku to host my app and when I run `git push heroku main` it gives me the following error: `panicked at 'the global thread pool has not been initialized.: threadpool builderror { kind: ioerror(error { kind: unsupported, message: "operation not supported on this platform" }) }'`

How should I solv this issue ?
Language = NextJS
hosting = Heroku

And here is my package.json, full error log & next.config.js

## package.json

```
{
  "name": "invoice-website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x",
    "npm": "8.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/cache": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/server": "^11.10.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.105",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.11",
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cookie": "^0.5.0",
    "feather-icons-react": "^0.5.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.7.0",
    "next": "^12.2.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-infinite-scroll-component": "^6.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.4",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "eslint": "8.26.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.18",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.1"
  }
}
```

## Full ERROR Log

```
remote:        info  - Creating an optimized production build...
remote: warn  - Found lockfile missing swc dependencies, run next locally to automatically patch
remote:        info  - Downloading WASM swc package...
remote:        info  - Using experimental wasm build of next-swc
remote: warn  - Attempted to load @next/swc-linux-x64-gnu, but it was not installed
remote: warn  - Attempted to load @next/swc-linux-x64-gnux32, but it was not installed
remote: warn  - Attempted to load @next/swc-linux-x64-musl, but it was not installed
remote: panicked at 'The global thread pool has not been initialized.: ThreadPoolBuildError { kind: IOError(Error { kind: Unsupported, message: "operation not supported on this platform" }) }', /Users/runner/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rayon-core-1.9.1/src/registry.rs:170:10
remote:
remote: Stack:
remote:
remote: Error
remote:     at module.exports.__wbg_new_693216e109162396 (/tmp/build_4bef0c6e/node_modules/next/wasm/@next/swc-wasm-nodejs/wasm.js:202:17)  
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[5445]:0xf90917
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[13700]:0x11eca7b
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[9995]:0x1186adc
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[11009]:0x11b6862
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[12785]:0x11e5cdd
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[11383]:0x11c358f
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[10017]:0x1187e72
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[1151]:0x98decd
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[654]:0x75f3f2
remote:
remote:
remote: panicked at 'The global thread pool has not been initialized.: ThreadPoolBuildError { kind: GlobalPoolAlreadyInitialized }', /Users/runner/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rayon-core-1.9.1/src/registry.rs:170:10
remote:
remote: Stack:
remote:
remote: Error
remote:     at module.exports.__wbg_new_693216e109162396 (/tmp/build_4bef0c6e/node_modules/next/wasm/@next/swc-wasm-nodejs/wasm.js:202:17)  
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[5445]:0xf90917
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[13700]:0x11eca7b
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[9995]:0x1186adc
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[11009]:0x11b6862
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[12785]:0x11e5cdd
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[11383]:0x11c358f
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[10017]:0x1187e72
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[1151]:0x98decd
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[654]:0x75f3f2
remote:
remote:
remote: Failed to compile.
remote:
remote: static/chunks/framework-e5dffe227a349f5b.js from Terser
remote: unreachable
remote: RuntimeError: unreachable
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[9995]:0x1186aff
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[11009]:0x11b6862
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[12785]:0x11e5cdd
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[11383]:0x11c358f
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[10017]:0x1187e72
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[1151]:0x98decd
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[654]:0x75f3f2
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[654]:0x760098
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[3154]:0xd6fe73
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[654]:0x75f24f
remote:
remote: static/chunks/80-ae3f54929433d50c.js from Terser
remote: unreachable
remote: RuntimeError: unreachable
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[9995]:0x1186afd
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[11009]:0x11b6862
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[12785]:0x11e5cdd
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[11383]:0x11c358f
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[10017]:0x1187e72
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[1151]:0x98decd
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[654]:0x75f3f2
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[654]:0x760098
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[3154]:0xd6fe73
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[654]:0x75f24f
remote:
remote: static/chunks/920-43714e5c99ca734b.js from Terser
remote: unreachable
remote: RuntimeError: unreachable
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[9995]:0x1186afd
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[11009]:0x11b6862
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[12785]:0x11e5cdd
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[11383]:0x11c358f
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[10017]:0x1187e72
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[1151]:0x98decd
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[654]:0x75f3f2
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[654]:0x760098
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[3154]:0xd6fe73
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[654]:0x75f24f
remote:
remote: static/chunks/153-7f28d108df7ea80a.js from Terser
remote: unreachable
remote: RuntimeError: unreachable
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[9995]:0x1186afd
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[11009]:0x11b6862
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[12785]:0x11e5cdd
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[11383]:0x11c358f
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[10017]:0x1187e72
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[1151]:0x98decd
remote:     at wasm://wasm/059aa236:wasm-function[654]:0x75f3f2
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
```

## next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

I tried using latest `node` version and old `node@16` version but none of them worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like an issue with the swcMinify option in the nextConfig, try setting it to false.

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: false,
};
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked, and I have also found alternative solution for this is to clone the app from heroku git directory and update the changes there and push. It also worked. But for now netlify is the best option and alternative for heroku